# Azure function: during zip deployment, is there a convenient way to completely remove old contents in `wwwroot`?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using the Azure CLI to perform Zip Deployment for Azure functions:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n \
<app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

After it runs, project files are in the `/home/site/wwwroot`;

However, when I make changes to my project and deploy again (say I removed an unused script), then the files from the previous deploy still exists in the `wwwroot` folder, even though they are removed in the update.

During deployment, is there a convenient way to completely remove old contents in `wwwroot` and put files of new zip deployment into it?

I am looking for something like a `--clean` flag in the `az functionapp deployment` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

I have deployed my function app twice and updated and removed files and checked if there are any old files and I observed that old files are removed or been updated so, what you are experiencing is not normal.

Command which I used:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "resourcegrpname" -n "func app name"  --src "FunctionApp2.zip"
```

[image]

So, I would suggest you to raise a support request as this is not a expected behavior and this also may be happen because of func app corruption.

One way to delete them is by below way:

[image]

and there is no option to clean or use **`--clean`**.